# Как вывести на страницу дату в определённом формате?

Tags: javascript, html, дата

Никак не могу разобраться как в хедер сайта вывести дату в формате Sunday,12th December.

Comment: На нативном JS или используете библиотеку moment.js ? Покажите Ваши попытки, пожалуйста.

Comment: На нативном, попытки привели только к отображению даты в числовом формате, по типу 11.03.2020.

Comment: добавьте код, который работает некорректно

Comment: Благодарю я сделал уже через moment.js

Comment: @UlrichZven лучше использовать [dayjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dayjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
const d = new Date();
var date = `${days[d.getDay()]}, ${d.getDate()}th ${monthNames[d.getMonth()]}.`;
document.write(date);
```